# gitignore ignore files within a folder that has whitespace in the middle

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I have a folder that have a space in the middle, but have a webconfig file inside it. I want git to ignore the webconfig file but somehow it's not ignoring it because of the space in the folder. Anybody know how to work around this?

```
My FolderName/Web.config
```

I tried to insert the `%20` in the middle but that did not help.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you could use a * or do you want to force that there is a whitespace?

Comment: Just in case anybody stumbles across this and wonders why %20 won't work, it's because %20 is unique to URL encoding.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Try `My\ FolderName/Web.config` or `"My FolderName/Web.config"`

Comment: My\ FolderName/Web.config worked for me. "My FolderName/Web.config" did not work for me.

Comment: On Windows, `My\ FolderName` worked for me as well.
Thanks!

Comment: For me none of your methods worked on windows 10 64bit.

Comment: For me, windows requires the latter and linux the former. If you have to support both (I do), I'm not sure what you are supposed to do.

Comment: Also, it would appear, that if a file is already tracked, just putting it in .gitignore will not stop tracking it.  You need to add the file to ignore to .gitignore, then remove it from the local system, let the removal propogate to the origin, then put the file back in the local system.  I'm sure there is a more efficient way, but however you do it, you need to undo the existing tracking in addition to getting the pattern right in the .gitignore file.

Comment: @aggieNick02 Since there's nothing wrong in having unused rules in your `.gitignore`, you could put both forms and it'll work fine.

Comment: @JamesMadison `git rm` or `git rm --cached` to untrack a now-ignored file which was previously added to tracking.

Comment: Backslash-escaping worked for me both on Linux and Windows 10.
Using the file path without escaping or quoting also worked on both.
Quoting did not work on either.

Answer (score -4):

I'm guessing you probably have to use `"My FolderName"/Web.config` instead.