# file that I removed from github repository keeps showing up in pull requests

Tags: git

For the longest time, I had two classes of system-generated files that kept showing up in my pull requests:

- cache files
- test case properties file

The latter was in `.gitignore`

It turns out that I had them on the master branch of the repository. I [followed these steps](https://blog.terresquall.com/2022/06/how-to-fix-gitignore-not-working-on-your-repository/#fixing-the-issue) to remove them from there...

, as well as git-ignoring the cache files, which leaves my `.gitignore` looking like this:

```
.gradle

bin

Reports

Libs

output

!output/.gitkeep
build

.classpath

.project

# Added by Mike Warren
"Zoho Katalon Project/settings/internal/com.kms.katalon.composer.testcase.properties"
"Zoho Katalon Project/.cache/**/*"
```

This works to completely remove any cache files from my changesets (and therefore pull requests)...

...but for some odd reason, the `Zoho Katalon Project/settings/internal/com.kms.katalon.composer.testcase.properties` file still remains in my changeset, despite that the file is no longer part of master branch!

I keep having to say `git rm --cached "Zoho Katalon Project/settings/internal/com.kms.katalon.composer.testcase.properties"` just to get it out of my changeset!

[image]

What can I do to make sure that this file is gone for good from any change sets (present or future)?

Comment: After `git rm`, did you run `git commit`?

Comment: Yes, there's no instance of the file on my repository anymore.

Comment: Do not use double quotes in the `.gitignore` file unless there are literal double quotes in the path name (which seems quite unlikely).

Comment: What should I do if the path name contains spaces then?

Comment: @MikeWarren https://stackoverflow.com/a/10213746/7976758 but see [the 1st comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213653/gitignore-ignore-files-within-a-folder-that-has-whitespace-in-the-middle#comment18790639_10213746) . Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitignore%5D+space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with one weird trick...

Per [@phd's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74593755/file-that-i-removed-from-github-repository-keeps-showing-up-in-pull-requests?noredirect=1#comment131673288_74593755)...

I just had to change:

```
"Zoho Katalon Project/settings/internal/com.kms.katalon.composer.testcase.properties"
"Zoho Katalon Project/.cache/**/*"
```

to:

```
Zoho\ Katalon Project/settings/internal/com.kms.katalon.composer.testcase.properties
Zoho\ Katalon Project/.cache/**/*
```

!